# What does double type declarations in TypeScript mean?

Tags: angular, typescript

I was doing the Angular tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#error-handling)

The following piece of code have double type declarations, but I don't understand what it means.

```
handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
   return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);

      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      return of(result as T);
   };
}
```

So error is declared as of type any, then there's another colon to declare a function with Observable as the parameter. What exactly is it returning?

Comment: The handleError function returns a function which receives an error parameter and  returns Observable<T>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return a type which is a ***function***. It takes an `error: any` and returns `Observable<T>`.

```
(error: any): Observable<T>
```

After this you initialize your variable with a function which has body

```
=> {
      console.error(error);

      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      return of(result as T);
};
```

So your `handleError` **returns a function with signature taking a parameter of type `any` and returning an `Observable<T>`**

```
(error: any): Observable<T>
```

Comment: man, that's confusing sometimes with all the brackets. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
return (error: any): Observable<T> => { ... }
```

That returns a function, taking an argument named `error`, of type `any`, whose return type is `Observable<T>`, and whose body is between the curly braces.